# When is the best time to discuss contract rate for renewal?

Tags: contracts

I'm working as a consulting engineer.

I'd be available for about one month after my contract expires, at which point I head back to school for an MBA.

I'd stay on (for the extra month) for an increase in rate, but otherwise would be happy to travel for the month before school begins.

Given this, is it best to wait for the company to approach me with their renewal rate, or should I bring up the fact that I'd like a higher rate prior to that?

I was thinking of letting them know 4 weeks before contract expiry.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd stay on (for the extra month) for an increase in rate, but
>   otherwise would be happy to travel for the month before school begins.
>
> Given this, is it best to wait for the company to approach me with
>   their renewal rate, or should I bring up the fact that I'd like a
>   higher rate prior to that?
>
> I was thinking of letting them know 4 weeks before contract expiry.

If I understand you correctly, you are saying if (and only if) you get a rate increase, then you'll consent to stay on for 1 month extra. Otherwise, you will leave at the end of the contract.

**It makes sense to tell them your intentions and your requirements around 4 weeks before your contract ends, or sooner, if they bring up the topic of your final month first.**

In my experience, I never change the rate for contractors when I extend them. I certainly wouldn't even entertain a rate hike for a 1-month contract extension, but your situation may be different. You may be in a critical position where one additional month is extremely important, and the hiring manager happens to have extra budget for rate increases.